# Sequelize return String type column value as Buffer array (MariaDB)

Tags: mariadb, sequelize.js

I'm using sequelize(http://docs.sequelizejs.com/) as ORM library in my node.js project.

DBMS is MariaDB (10.1.13-MariaDB - MariaDB Server)

The problem is, all VARCHAR and CHAR type column value returned as Buffer Array.
[image]

Table Structure is like this.
[image]

Model file is looks like this.
[image]

I don't know what I did wrong.

This is what I expect.

"user_id" : "asdfff"

"email_address" : "asdf@asdf.com"

...

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem myself.
I don't know why this happend.
If I connect to MySQL Database, String returned as String. It seems ok.
But only when I connec to Maria Database, String retured as Int Array (ints represents ASCII code of characters)

I've been struggled few days, but I couldn't figure out the point.
So I determined to edit one of sequelize's module file.

It is "node_modules/sequelize/lib/instance.js"

last part of the function "Instance.prototype.set = function(key, value, options...",
I added few lines of code.

```
    if (!options.raw && ((!Utils.isPrimitive(value) && value !== null) || value !== originalValue)) {
      this._previousDataValues[key] = originalValue;
      this.changed(key, true);
    }

    // HACK : This part for byte array to string of MariaDB
    if (Buffer.isBuffer(value)) {
        value = value.toString('utf8');
    }

    this.dataValues[key] = value;
```

I'm not sure this is good solution but in my case, any problem not happend so far.

Comment: For future readers, it's best not to edit the library. If you believe you've discovered a bug, report it. Otherwise, fix it in your own code. In this case, a custom getter would have helped: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-definition.html#getters-setters